# Node-Serialport Import Error: exists is not a function in node_modules/bindings.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, electron, node-serialport

Hello I am developing an IOT app and for that I'm using

**NodeJs, Electron, React Redux and Node-SerialPort.**

I tried few times but I always get stuck in making serialport work with this setup. 
Also even, just the import is causing all these problems. The breaking change is 
the import code itself :

**const SerialPort = require('serialport');**

The first error that I get is

**exists is not a function in node_modules/bindings.js**

If I fix that by making changes in bindings file then again I get an error in the same file:

**Require is not defined**

and so on..

Also, I'm working on MacOS High Sierra.

Comment: Better if you share your code

Comment: Umm, i know it will be helpful but it's a big project with react, redux and electron setup and components. I'm not sure what to include and what not..
But the breaking code is just 
**const SerialPort = require('serialport');**. I have edited the question and also I think I can update the question Title too.

Comment: I do not know if it is possible to use node-serialport on client side. I have never used. But if you did not mention node.js then you use it client side. Try import instead require.

Comment: tried that too and I'm running it on server only and yes I'm using nodejs. Electron works with node js only. I will update the question to reflect that.

Comment: did you read? "When you first install serialport it will compile against the version of Node.js on your machine, not against the Node.js runtime bundled with Electron." see Electron https://serialport.io/docs/en/guide-installation

Comment: Yes, I followed the steps too but got the same error. Tried other node modules such as "usb" but getting errors too.. if you know other good usb/serialport modules, then let me know..

Comment: Maybe this helps [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57715708/how-to-implement-serialport-io-with-electron-and-react/59701121#59701121](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57715708/how-to-implement-serialport-io-with-electron-and-react/59701121#59701121)